# css flex one item on the left and 2 items on the right under each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 div containers and I want first div container to be on left side and be as large in height as 2 containers on the right side, but the problem is that the containers on right side are not wrapped in one parent container. Basically what I want to do -
[image: html structure]

Is it even possible to do it without changing html structure? Or only possible solution would be to wrap those 2 elements in one parent container?

Here is my html structure -

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">text here</div>
  <div class="block2">text here</div>
  <div class="block3">text here</div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

i made with `grid`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  height:400px;
}

.container div {
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.block1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background:red;
}

.block2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  background:greenyellow;
}

.block3 {
 grid-row: 3 / 5;
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block1">text here 1</div>
  <div class="block2">text here 2</div>
  <div class="block3">text here3</div>
</div>
```